# How to add more font sizes for label in xcode 8 in xcode 7 it shows '+' symbol in beside font

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uilabel, adaptive-ui

[image]

i want to implement the individual sizes for uilabel in all devices and ipad in iphone devices it working where as in ipad it not increasing please help

thanks in advance

Comment: i am unable to find adaptive layout in xcode 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had simillar issue. It seems that for some `xib's` you need to manually turn trait variations on in Xcode 8.

[image]

Comment: you know how to increase trade mark symbol height in label             file:///Users/apple/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202016-09-27%20at%207.50.28%20PM.png

Comment: Your screenshot didn't get uploaded, rather a refernce to local file on your drive got :)

Comment: Easiest way would be to add it as a separate label with bigger font size.